# how do i fix these errors my debug log gave me?

Tags: errors

Hi i have a strange loading issue with my website, this is what my debug log just gave me. How do i fix these errors?

> [11-Dec-2018 20:25:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset
>   'http_code' in
>   /home/viralclo/public_html/wp-content/themes/multinews/framework/addons/auto-updates/class-envato-protected-api.php
>   on line 307
>
> [11-Dec-2018 20:25:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset
>   'api_error' in
>   /home/viralclo/public_html/wp-content/themes/multinews/framework/addons/auto-updates/class-envato-protected-api.php
>   on line 307
>
> [11-Dec-2018 20:25:26 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function()
>   is deprecated in
>   /home/viralclo/public_html/wp-content/themes/multinews/framework/admin/fonts-option/class.settings-api.php
>   on line 115
>
> [11-Dec-2018 20:25:48 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:
>   fb-instant-page-id in
>   /home/viralclo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/accelerated-mobile-pages/templates/features.php
>   on line 4298
>
> [11-Dec-2018 20:25:55 UTC] PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric
>   value encountered in
>   /home/viralclo/public_html/wp-content/themes/multinews/framework/functions/rimages.php
>   on line 280
>
> [11-Dec-2018 20:26:14 UTC] PHP Notice:  get_bloginfo was called with
>   an argument that is **deprecated** since version 2.2.0!
>   The `siteurl` option is deprecated for the family of
>   `bloginfo()` functions. Use the `url` option
>   instead. in /home/viralclo/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on
>   line 4053

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the theme you are using `multinews` is using deprecated functions for your version of PHP. See if you can get an updated copy of the theme from the theme author or downgrade your PHP version to pre `7.2`

EDIT: Request to edit code.

You can update the code by navigating to the file and the line and updating the line(s) to non-deprecated code.

Example:

```
[11-Dec-2018 20:25:26 UTC] PHP Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/viralclo/public_html/wp-content/themes/multinews/framework/admin/fonts-option/class.settings-api.php on line 115
```

There is a deprecated function (`create_function()`) in:

```
wp-content/themes/multinews/framework/admin/fonts-option/class.settings-api.php
```

The end of the error lets you know which line.

`on line 115`

In this case you can look at an article like:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated to see if you can update the deprecated code.

Comment: The support is terrible for my theme, is there a way i can update the code myself? if so where would i find the new code to replace the old?

Comment: @Chris I updated my answer. The issue is caused by the version of PHP you are using.